# Record current target in Makefile

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

At present I have a Makefile with a multiple target rule. It records the target and then invokes a new Make with that target set.

E.g.

```
$(LIST_OF_PRODUCTS) : 
     @echo Making $@
     @make build_product PRODUCT=$@
```

The output directory and binary then use this product name..

How do I record the target currently being built in a multi-target rule without invoking a new Make instance?

I have tried:

```
$(LIST_OF_PRODUCTS) : PRODUCT := $@
$(LIST_OF_PRODUCTS) : build_product
      @echo Making $(PRODUCT) Done.
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve in `build_product`, you may be able to use `define` to create sort of a template for a rule, which you can then call with the combination of `$(eval ...)` and `$(call ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The best I came up with is the GNU make template method:

```
#
# Template for creating a target
define target-template
.PHONY : ${1}
${1} : TARGET_NAME:=${1}
${1} : check_target $$(OBJECTS)
endef

#
#Generate targets from template
$(foreach target,$(TARGET_LIST),$(eval $(call target-template,$(target))))
```

However its just pushed my problem elsewhere. Since check_target is only called once when that targets are called via a group?

E..g

```
all : target_a target_b
```

Comment: It's still not clear what are you trying to achieve. I have a feeling that it could be done simpler.